# Publish App outside of the US and have it be available in the US Appstore

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Is it possible to publish an app to the local regional appstore and have it be available to the US Appstore or will it only be available to the store it was published to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your app in iTunesConnect there is a section for setting its price and what countries it is available in. You can specify that is is available everywhere or just in certain countries.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. Clear and concise!